# send location to server in background - ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, cllocationmanager, multitasking

I try to send the user location in background when application received silent push.

my code:

> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:

looks like:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
          bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
[_cllManager startUpdatingLocation];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
```

> locationManager:didUpdateLocations:

looks like:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
    bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
              bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];
    // here I'm sending the request to server via AFNetworking
    [_cllManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
```

I tried to send a silent push to myself

- the push always arrived to my device
- sometimes the request was sent immediately
- sometimes the request was sent but I can't see it in my log
- sometimes the request wasn't sent - but when I opened the application, all unsent requests - was sent
- sometimes the request unsent at all

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Silent push notification is unreliable and it can't does not guaranteed to be delivered on device always if the normal push notification is been enabled for same services /device .

My suggestion would be use the 
1)significant location change features of apple .
2)use Region Monitoring

Both can done in background mode .

Comment: thanks, but significant or regions are not help me.
Reported the location is independent of the any area or distance.
I want to decide when to get information about the user's location.

Comment: Do you have any reference to the claim that the Silent Push mechanism is unreliable?

Comment: @zeevblu yes you can also do that . But Remember once you stop your location manager in background you won't be able send location repeatedly , your application will suspend after you call [locationManager stopUpdating ];

Comment: @AdamMatan sure -- http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/